# Mass lossage of a human over iterative falling due to heat

Tags: thermodynamics, gravity, mass

I watching a video that mentioned that a meteor loses mass as it falls via energy being converted to heat, so say we are on the Burj Khalif ($828$ meters), how many times would a human, say $6$ ft tall and weighing $150$ lbs, have to fall from the top to lose all of their mass (including or excluding things like metabolism, answer-er's preference), if they teleported back to the starting elevation of the building in Portal-esque fashion and continued falling, instead of becoming a wet puddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meteor losing mass due to losing energy is a technicality, ignorable in virtually all circumstances.  If I go to one of my favorite tables on the internet, [Orders of Magnitude (Energy)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_(energy)), we can see that the meteor that killed the dinosaurs released $5\cdot10^{23} \text J$.  A simple trip through $E=mc^2$ shows that that is equivalent to a mere 5,000,000 kg.  The [meteor involved in said event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicxulub_impactor), of course, is believed to have had a mass on the order of 10,000,000,000,000,000kg, so 5 million kg was a mere 0.00000005% of the story.  The dinosaurs certainly never noticed!

Also, the meteors fall from a much greater height.  You can emit a great deal more heat dropping at hypersonic speeds than at human speeds.

But c'est la vie.  Let's run some numbers!

[Human terminal velocity](https://www.fai.org/page/isc-speed-skydiving) is on the order of 55m/s.  I'm assuming the human involved in this experiment is not here voluntarily, so will likely try to spread themselves out into a stable skydiving belly-first fall.You reach 55m/s in somewhere around 6 seconds (hand waving drag for simplicity), and manage to fall about 170m in this time.  Now since you describe this is a Portal-escque teleport, I'm going to assume that they only have to accelerate the first time.  All subsequent times will start at terminal velocity.  I'll ignore this first one.  It really doesn't matter.  We're going to be doing so many falls starting at terminal velocity that we can just focus on them.

This makes the math easy.  Since the person's velocity is the same at the start as it is at the end, 100% of the gravitational potential energy goes into drag, which eventually becomes heat.  The gravitational potential energy at the top is $PE=mgh$.  Mass is 68kg, g is 9.89m/s2, and h is 828m, for a total of 0.5MJ per fall.

Now we just plug this back into $E=mc^2$ to get a mass of 0.000000000005563kg.

We're going to be here a while.  To burn off 34kg at that rate will take 6,000,000,000,000 falls, each lasting 15 seconds for a total of 2,905,135 years of falling.

And I'll note I'm handwaving away something very important.  Your portal is providing exactly the same amount of energy into the person during the teleport, and we're not accounting for it.

But, regardless, the reality is that the relativistic mass losses are so slight that our human will decide infinite portal falling is no fun *long* before we start to see measurable mass losses.

And, given how difficult it would be to get them food during that time, this would also qualify as the ultimate weight loss program... at least while they are still alive.

*Indeed, I do think that if we take this vertical situation, and rotate it to be horizontal, [we've seen it before.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fFufoOgCMW8)*

Comment: Why is the portal providing the same amount of energy into the person each teleport a problem?

Comment: @SchreyerKarl because it puts the human 828m higher than when they entered the portal.  That increases the potential energy of the human by mgh, which is exactly what is dissipated on the way down.

Comment: This was both funny and informative! Well done Cort.

Comment: That was my guess, awesome!